# Readable C++\CLI Exception Message in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, c++-cli

the following code throws an exception in C++ and catch in C#
C++

```
 throw std::exception ("a C++ exception");
```

When i catch in C#, it gives me the following:

```
[SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
```

here is how i call the C++ code

```
using Foo.Bar.Sample; //C++ library

....

Class1 class1 = new Class1(); //C++ class
class1.throwAnException();
```

Just wondering how can i get the "a C++ exception" in C#

Comment: Have you checked the stack trace? What does the exception `ToString()` have in it?

Comment: How are you calling your C++ code from C#? Via PInvoke?

Comment: @ Matteo, i just modified the question to clarify

Comment: @Oded I print out the ToString() and could not find exception message there. thanks

Comment: @Martin I trid std::runtime_error too. got the same exception message

Comment: According to the standard std::exception does not have a constructor that takes any arguments. Generally you should use one of the standard exceptions derived from std::exception like std::runtime_error. Your implementation obviously has a non standard std::exception but to write portable code this should not be relied upon. See Section 18.7.1 of the C++ standard

Comment: @ jebberwocky: Sorry I don;t actually know how to solve your actual problem. I was just commenting on the use of std::exception rather than std::runtime_error.

Comment: @jebberwocky: if you're using the C++ class via `using`, I think that the C++ class is written in C++/CLI, am I right? In that case I think you should just throw "normal" .NET exceptions.

Comment: @Matteo i am not really similar with C++, since i use C# mainly. if that is the case, how i throw a "normal" .NET exceptions in C++ project? is there any reference to read? By the way, i created the c++ project by Visual Studio Wizard, Visual C++ -> Class Library. thanks

Comment: @jebberwocky: if you created it as a Class Library, it's almost surely a C++/CLI project, i.e. an hybrid of C++ (which in it's "normal" flavour is unmanaged) and .NET; I added the relevant tag. You probably want to do something like `throw gcnew System::IO::FileNotFoundException();` or whatever .NET exception you want to throw, but I'm not familiar with C++/CLI, so don't trust too much my advices.

Comment: @Matteo thanks. i know how to work on it now. thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Didn't ask the question correctly***. It is `C++\CLI` not `C++` exception. In C++\CLI, do the following:

```
 throw gcnew System::Exception("It is a C++\CLI exception");
```

rather than c++ native exception

thank you all for answering and commenting

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you always catch exceptions with the same runtime that threw them.

And the only way to analyze the exception is from C++, since the layout of the exception isn't defined.

Answer (score 2):

As @CodeInChaos explained, C++ and .NET have different runtimes so the exceptions do not coexist very well.

Can you use C++/CLI for the C++ part ? This will unify the runtime and the exceptions will be compatible. Note that you can have a small part of the C++ code that uses .NET (mixed-mode code).

Comment: C++/CLI is using in my case. how should i throw my exception properly in C++/CLI thanks